# Best way to migrate from EF4 to EF6

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-4.3

I have an existing application based on EF4 model first which I need to upgrade to use EF6.

- It includes a number of inherited tables (Table Per Type), so ideally
  I want this to be maintained after the upgrade.
- I have some complex types which I would also like supported (not so important).
- I want to include the foreign key Id columns too which were not included in the
  EF4 version.

I tried a simple 'Generate from existing database' but this does not give me all I need (no inheritance, no complex type support). Maybe I am asking too much here!!

**UPDATE**

On the advise of marc_s (answer below - thanks!) I followed the instructions at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/upgradeef6.aspx and it worked like a dream!

Comment: Have you checked out / tried out [Upgrading to Entity Framework 6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/upgradeef6.aspx) ?

Comment: I've just come across this article! Doh! Let me give that a go and I'll report back :-) thanks marc_s

Comment: Original link broken. Updated link seems to be: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/what-is-new/upgrading-to-ef6